# textDidChange vs controlTextDidChange

Tags: objective-c

**Can someone explain me why textDidChange isn't handling my delegate but controlTextDidChange works from NSTextField.**

```
 - (void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification{
    NSBeep();
}
```

from

```
 - (void)textDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification{
    NSBeep();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`controlTextDidChange:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/controlTextDidChange:) is the correct delegate method defined on `NSTextField` (inherited from `NSControl`).

[`textDidChange:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextField_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTextField/textDidChange:) is a method that, when called on `NSTextField`, makes it behave as if its text changed (including calling the above method).  It is not a delegate method for you to implement.

It's a little inconsistent of Apple as they do have a `textDidChange:` delegate method on [UISearchBarDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 1):

textDidChange: `Informs the delegate that the text object has changed its characters or formatting attributes.`

I'm guessing that means its font (text attributes) changes, and not the text inputted.