# NSTextView textDidChange event

Tags: swift

I'm doing something similar to:

```
@IBOutlet var textView: NSTextView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    textView.delegate = self
}

func textDidChange(notification: NSNotification) {

}
```

I did add "NSTextViewDelegate" at the very beginning.

I want to set the string value of a label if the text in the "textView" is changed.

The problem is that my program will just crash without any error message (breakpoint is at "fun textDidChange()......"). It will crash even if the func textDidChange is empty.

Am I doing anything wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: The console output might help !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use this, Swift 3

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTextViewDelegate {

  @IBOutlet var textView: NSTextView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    textView.delegate = self

  // NSTextViewDelegate conforms to NSTextDelegate
  func textDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
    guard let textView = notification.object as? NSTextView else { return }
    print(textView.string)
  }
}
```

Remember

- There is a `_` in `textDidChange(_ notification: Notification)`
- Swift 3 prefers `Notification` instead of `NSNotification`
- Set a delegate `textView.delegate = self`

Answer (score 0):

See this answer: [textDidChange vs controlTextDidChange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12227975/textdidchange-vs-controltextdidchange)

In short, use `controlTextDidChange:` instead.

Comment: The answer from @onmyway133 is the correct one. `ControlTextDidChange` only applies to `NSTextField`. The question is about `NSTextView`