# UITextField layout superview after appending text

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I have UITableView with 2 UITextField elements in each row placed horizontally.
[image]

I want right UITextField automatically enlarge when I append text, but layout only happens when I end editing text.

[image]
[image]

I tried adding this code to UITableViewCell but it doesn't work

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(BillPositionCell.textDidChange), name: UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification, object: self.sumTextField)
}

func textDidChange() {
    self.sumTextField.setNeedsLayout()
    self.sumTextField.layoutIfNeeded()
    self.contentView.setNeedsLayout()
    self.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just give the textfield the biggest width possible? with clear color background, you don't see the rectangle block but just the text.

Comment: Because I have another textfield to the right and I don't want to waste space

Answer (score 0):

Try:(width is sumTextField width NSLayoutConstraint)

```
func textDidChange() {
    let newSize = sumTextField.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(CGFloat.max, CGFloat.max))
    width.constant = newSize.width
    layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

See this answer: [textDidChange vs controlTextDidChange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12227975/textdidchange-vs-controltextdidchange)

In short, use controlTextDidChange: instead.

Comment: 1. It's iOS, not OS X 2. My textDidChange function is called, I placed breakpoint inside it